# Sum of Two Continuous Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus, actuarial-science

Consider two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$. Let $$f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 − x/2,  & \text{if $0\le x\le 2$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$.Let $$f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
2-2y,  & \text{if $0\le y\le 1$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$. Find the probability density function of $X + Y$.

Can anyone show me a step by step solution to this problem?

I've been applying this theorem to solve the problem with limited success [image]

Comment: It  is the convolution of the two densities, assuming independence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Z=X+Y$. We know $0\leq Z\leq 3$ but for the density of $Z$ we have three cases to consider due to the ranges of $X$ and $Y$.

If $0\leq z\leq 1$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_Z(z) &=& \int_{x=0}^{z} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\;dx \\
&=& \int_{x=0}^{z} (1-x/2)(2-2y)\;dx \\
&=& \left[ 2x-2zx+zx^2/2+x^2/2-x^3/3 \right]_{x=0}^{z} \\
&=& 2z - \dfrac{3}{2}z^2 + \dfrac{1}{6}z^3.
\end{eqnarray*}

If $1\lt z\leq 2$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_Z(z) &=& \int_{x=z-1}^{z} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\;dx \\
&=& \int_{x=z-1}^{z} (1-x/2)(2-2y)\;dx \\
&=& \left[ 2x-2zx+zx^2/2+x^2/2-x^3/3 \right]_{x=z-1}^{z} \\
&=& \dfrac{7}{6} - \dfrac{1}{2}z.
\end{eqnarray*}

If $2\lt z\leq 3$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_Z(z) &=& \int_{x=z-1}^{2} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\;dx \\
&=& \int_{x=z-1}^{2} (1-x/2)(2-2y)\;dx \\
&=& \left[ 2x-2zx+zx^2/2+x^2/2-x^3/3 \right]_{x=z-1}^{2} \\
&=& \dfrac{9}{2} - \dfrac{9}{2}z + \dfrac{3}{2}z^2 - \dfrac{1}{6}z^3.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Mick, I'm not completely sure how you chose the bounds for the different integrals- do you mind briefly explaining?

Comment: @aman1230 For $0\leq z\leq 1:\;$ Here, $x$ must be less than $z$ since $y$ can't be negative. So we must have $0\lt x\lt 1$.

For $1\lt z\leq 2:\;$ Again, $x$ must be less than $z$ since $y$ can't be negative. Also, since $y\lt 1$, we must have $x$ at least $z-1$. Thus, $z-1\lt x\lt z$.

For $2\lt z\leq 3:\;$ Again, since $y\lt 1$, we must have $x$ at least $z-1$. Also, $x$ cannot exceed $2$ so that instead of $z$ is the upper limit here. Thus, $z-1\lt x\lt 2$.

I hope that helps explain it.

Comment: This is quite intuitive Mick. I appreciate your help. Thanks.